# Apache Webserver - PHP - Dynamic Vhost - Shell

Tags: php, bash, apache, shell, web

> thanks for your time. I've problem with my school work. We have create
>   a webserver on apache, with gui for registration "domain". The server
>   is VPN, i.e the domain name will not be domain.cz, for example, but
>   domain.ourserver.cz.

How it works:

PHP run shell script, which look like this: (this is test version yet)

```
    #!/bin/bash

    touch /var/www/log.txt

    function createDirectory() {
            mkdir "/var/www/$1"
            chmod -R g+rw "/var/www/$1"
    }

    function createFtpUser() {
            echo "writing password" >> /var/www/log.txt
            echo $2 > /var/www/passfile

            echo "writing password 2" >> /var/www/log.txt
            echo $2 >> /var/www/passfile

            echo "creating ftp user $1" >> /var/www/log.txt
            pure-pw useradd "$1" -u ftpuser -d "/var/www/$1" -m < /var/www/passfile

            echo "updating database" >> /var/www/log.txt
            pure-pw mkdb

            echo "deleting temp passwd file" >> /var/www/log.txt
            rm -f /var/www/fei-ispwe-5/passfile

            echo "-------------------------------------" >> /var/www/log.txt
    }

    function createIndexFile() {
            echo "<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>" > /var/www/$1/index.html


createDirectory $1
createFtpUser $1 $2
createIndexFile $1
exit
                                                         1,1
```

If I run this script with: #bash webscript.sh admin "123456", all works well. But, if I run this shell from php:

```
exec("bash '/var/www/webscript.sh' 'mydomain' '123456'", $output);
```

> script won't return the error, all looks well, bud the user won't be
>   create.

Our directory structure:

```
/var/www/
  -  webscript.sh
  -  passfile (two same rows with password for pure-pw useradd in out of script is deleted)
  -  fei-ispwe-5 (domain directory)
      - sourcecode of main page
  -  other directory, created by webscript.sh for Dyn. vhost
      - index.html (generated from webscript.sh)
```

The passfile is created and contains both same rows with passwords. The folder is success created too and if I enter the url mydomain.outserver.cz, I'll see "It works!"

Only pure ftpd user didn't create.

What is wrong? Thanks a lot.

Comment: kindly check and share the log for the command `pure-pw useradd "$1" -u ftpuser -d "/var/www/$1" -m < /var/www/passfile`  if it can be executed correctly , seems an issue with this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Logs look corrent. In shell script (file: log.txt) are all lines.  

writing password
writing password 2
...

In log php ($output variable): there are no bugs.